# Python - Pandas - Create a column valid_until based on updated_at column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that has an `index`, `person_id`, and `updated_at` columns. I want to derive a new data frame that will have, `available` and `valid_untill` based on the `updated_at` column. Basically the `person_id` can repeat and only the last updated row for each `person_id` will have `valid_untill` as null.

Raw data:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Any idea how can I do this?

id=[1,2,1,1]
updated_at=['12/31/2019','12/30/2019','01/15/2020','01/20/2020']

dict={'id':id,'updated_at':updated_at}

df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show your research, namely, what you have tried. We can't write code for you, but would be more inclined to help if we saw your code and what went wrong.

Comment: We have a lot of ideas but first you need to follow a few advice: ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Also, in addition to rajah9's comment, please post these example tables as code so that we can copy-paste it easily into our Python environments. Noone wants to spent 30 min on typing data into a console...

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. "How do I do this" isn't a valid question, do you have an actual issue? See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (although - please don't call your column `index` - this will complicate things here):

```py
df["updated_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df["updated_at"])

df2=df.reset_index().merge(df.reset_index(), on="person_id", suffixes=["_x", "_y"])
df2["match"]=np.logical_and(df2["index_x"].lt(df2["index_y"]), df2["updated_at_x"].lt(df2["updated_at_y"]))
df["valid_until"]=df2.loc[df2["match"]].groupby("index_x")["updated_at_y"].first()
```

Outputs:

```py
   person_id updated_at valid_until
0          1 2019-12-31  2020-01-15
1          2 2019-12-30         NaT
2          1 2020-01-15  2020-01-20
3          1 2020-01-20         NaT
```

**Input data**:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"person_id": [1,2,1,1], "updated_at": "12/31/2019 12/30/2019 01/15/2020 01/20/2020".split(" ")})
```